# Adding onclick code from code behind formats it?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using code behind code to dynamically set javascriptcode into the onclick event. The problem is that I'm running into the strange phenomenon that the code gets formatted.
Thus:

```
    protected void HostJournalGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                string.Format("$(#detailDataRow{0}).addClass('overlayVisible');$(#detailDataRow{0}).removeClass('overlayHidden')",
                e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

Produces the following result:

```
</tr><tr class="JournalGridViewRow" onclick="$(#detailDataRow1).addClass(&#39;overlayVisible&#39;);$(#detailDataRow1).removeClass(&#39;overlayHidden&#39;)" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
```

the ' getting formatted into &#39.  Can I somehow avoid this?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `string.Format` call inside `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` e.g.

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
string.Format("$(#detailDataRow{0}).addClass('overlayVisible');$(#detailDataRow{0}).removeClass('overlayHidden')", e.Row.RowIndex));
```

The documentation is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8).